# 3D matrix addition python

Tags: python-3.x, indexoutofboundsexception, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to add 3D matrix but third loop is not starting from 0.
Here shape of matrix is (2,3,3).

Code:

```
for i in range(0,r):
    for j in range(0,c):
        for l in range(0,k):
            sum[i][j][k]=A1[i][j][k]+A2[i][j][k]
```

Output:

```
IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

Answer (score 0):

For element-wise addition of two matrices, you can simply use the + operator between two numpy arrays:

```
#create two matrices of random integers
matrix1 = np.random.randint(10, size=(2,3,3))
matrix2 = np.random.randint(10, size=(2,3,3))

#add the two matrices element-wise
sum_matrix = matrix1 + matrix2

print(matrix1, matrix2, sum_matrix, sep='\n__________\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get IndexError. Maybe you post your whole code?

This is my code:

```
arr1 = [[[2, 4, 8], [7, 7, 1], [4, 9, 0]], [[5, 0, 0], [3, 8, 6], [0, 5, 8]]]
arr2 = [[[3, 8, 0], [1, 5, 2], [0, 3, 9]], [[9, 7, 7], [1, 2, 5], [1, 1, 3]]]

sumArr = [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0]]]

for i in range(2): #can also use range(0,2)
    for j in range(3): 
        for k in range(3): 
            sumArr[i][j][k]=arr1[i][j][k]+arr2[i][j][k]
            
print(sumArr)
```

By the way, is it necessary to use for loop?
If not, you can use **numpy** library.

> import numpy as np

Convert your manual array to numpy matrix array, then do addition.

```
arr1 = [[[2, 4, 8], [7, 7, 1], [4, 9, 0]], [[5, 0, 0], [3, 8, 6], [0, 5, 8]]]
arr2 = [[[3, 8, 0], [1, 5, 2], [0, 3, 9]], [[9, 7, 7], [1, 2, 5], [1, 1, 3]]]

m1 = np.array(arr1)
m2 = np.array(arr2)

print("M1: \n", m1)
print("M2: \n", m2)
print("Sum: \n", m1 + m2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You iterate with 'l' in the third loop but to access in list, you used k. As a result, your code is trying to access k-th index which doesn't exists, and you're getting an error.

Use this:

```
    for i in range(0, r):
        for j in range(0, c): 
            for l in range(0, k): 
                sum[i][j][l] = A1[i][j][l] + A2[i][j][l]
```